# Arduino coding of producing frequency

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, frequency

Im new here. Anyone that could give a code or sample that would generate I wanted to use a frequency in range of 35k-43kHz. Please help me.

Comment: Sound a lot like an IR carrier wave.

Answer (score 3):

The code below generates 38 kHz and modulates its duty cycle.

```
// Example of modulating a 38 kHz frequency duty cycle by reading a potentiometer
// Author: Nick Gammon
// Date: 24 September 2012

const byte POTENTIOMETER = A0;
const byte LED = 10;  // Timer 1 "B" output: OC1B

// Clock frequency divided by 38 kHz frequency desired
const long timer1_OCR1A_Setting = F_CPU / 38000L;

void setup() 
 {
  pinMode (LED, OUTPUT);

  // set up Timer 1 - gives us 38.005 kHz 
  // Fast PWM top at OCR1A
  TCCR1A = bit (WGM10) | bit (WGM11) | bit (COM1B1); // fast PWM, clear OC1B on compare
  TCCR1B = bit (WGM12) | bit (WGM13) | bit (CS10);   // fast PWM, no prescaler
  OCR1A =  timer1_OCR1A_Setting - 1;                 // zero relative  
  }  // end of setup

void loop()
  {
  // alter Timer 1 duty cycle in accordance with pot reading
  OCR1B = (((long) (analogRead (POTENTIOMETER) + 1) * timer1_OCR1A_Setting) / 1024L) - 1;

  // do other stuff here
  }
```

Comment: Just to add; this code works for pin 10, and pin 10 alone.

Comment: I connected the output to the ultrasonic transmitter but its not working. here is the transmitter specification that i used (http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1498178.pdf) and the circuit diagram (https://www.google.com.ph/search?q=ultrasonic+circuit&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=643&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjoivap6-fJAhUK-2MKHdFeAFwQ_AUIBigB#tbm=isch&q=ultrasonic+transmitter+circuit+diagram&imgrc=fLTfT6_BQfBMyM%3A)

Comment: Not working? How do you know? Are you getting 38 kHz out of the Arduino or not? You would need an oscilloscope to check.

Answer (score 1):

use the 'tone' function:
[arduino tone function](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Tone)

example:

```
//tone(pinNumber, FrequencyInHertz);
tone(6, 35000); //generate a 35kHz tone on pin 6
delay(10);
tone(6, 43000); //generate a 43kHz tone on pin 6
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? This is basically a link-only answer which would not be helpful if the link went down.

Comment: I wanted to generate a set of high frequency at the range of 25k-60k Hz using the arduino uno. Please help me. What function do i use? I'm a newbie on coding and if anyone would share some code it would be a great help. Im very thankful.

Comment: @user13535 You now say 25k-60kHz, but your question says 38k-43kHz. Which is it?

Comment: The 25k-60k Hz. I change the range.

Answer (score -1):

This is meant to be a comment, but I can't put (pseudo) code in a comment.

A 40 kHz square wave? Simple:

```
for(;;){
   wait ( 1 / 2 * 40.000 );
   make pin high;
   wait ( 1 / 2 * 40.000 );
   make pin low;
}
```